# MySQL order by weighted fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table of content-tags for our articles and each tag is weighted 0-100 with the goal of having each article's tag-weight sum reach roughly 100. We don’t validate this, so potentially an article could have a lower or higher sum.

My table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `article_tags` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Data could look like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO `article_tags` (`article_id`, `tag, `weight`)
VALUES
  (1, 'fun', 50),
  (1, 'winter', 50),
  (2, 'fun', 10),
  (2, 'love', 10),
  (2, 'summer', 80)
  (3, 'fun', 40),
  (3, 'love', 50),
  (3, 'summer', 10),
```

Now I would like to be able to find all articles matching a given set of weighted tags.

So let's say the tags I have are `fun` 75% and `love` 25%. Now I wanna find the article best matching these tags and order by those counts.

I'm expecting to score the articles as follows:

- Article 1: fun 37.5%
- Article 3: fun 30%, love 12.5% = 32.5%
- Article 2: fun 7.5%, love 2.5% = 10%

As I'm both taking their `article_tags` weights into account and taking the requested weights for the tag lookups into account.

Can this be achieved with a MySQL query?

**UPDATE ON MATH**

My math is as follows:
My example shows a 4th article:

```
INSERT INTO `article_tags` (`article_id`, `tag, `weight`)
VALUES
  (4, 'fun', 75),
  (4, 'love', 25)
```

Now looking at that article I wanna find articles related to this 4th article.

So article 1 matches `fun` 50%, but as my 4th article only rates `fun` as 75% I'm deducting the weight of article 1: `50 * 0.75 = 37.5`.

There might be better math for this. My ultimate goal is to find related articles and taking each tag's weight into account while doing so.

Comment: how come article 1 fan percentage is 37.5%?

Comment: @Fahmi I wanna take the given keyword weights into account. So article 1 has fun scored at 50%, but I'm only gonna weight it 75% according to the lookup weight. There might be a better math for this, I just haven't found it :)

Comment: you tag datatype is wrong it must be varchar you have a selicolon too much after primary key and you data is missing one, please post your idea more clearly i still don't get why 75

Comment: Show us the formulas for the 37.5%, etc.

Comment: Unclear what your objective is (before putting it into a query).  If you are adding the weighted products, it looks like an article with 75/25 (which would seem to be a perfect match) would have a score of 62.75, while 100/0 would have a higher score at 75.  I would think you would want to weight the difference of the articles to the target and combine them in some way (probably not addition).  I'm sure any of the math can be put into SQL, but you need to get the math right first.

Comment: @nbk you are right on the varchar. My real world data references a normalized tag table. All: I've tried to better explain my math and ultimate goal. There might be a much prettier way of achieving this that I've missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your last update.

With this query you can find Article with a similar weight in tags. I put an example at the end.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `article_tags` (
>   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `article_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `tag` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `weight` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `article_tags` (`article_id`, `tag`, `weight`)
> VALUES
>   (1, 'fun', 50),
>   (1, 'winter', 50),
>   (2, 'fun', 10),
>   (2, 'love', 10),
>   (2, 'summer', 80),
>   (3, 'fun', 40),
>   (3, 'love', 50),
>   (3, 'summer', 10)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `article_tags` (`article_id`, `tag`, `weight`)
> VALUES
>   (4, 'fun', 75),
>   (4, 'love', 25)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     at1.`article_id`, `tag`, (`weight` / 100 * proc_per_id) correlated_weight
> FROM
>     article_tags at1
>         INNER JOIN
>     (SELECT 
>         `article_id`, SUM(`weight`) / COUNT(*) proc_per_id
>     FROM
>         article_tags
>     GROUP BY `article_id`) at2 ON at1.`article_id` = at2.`article_id`
> ```
>
> ```
> article_id | tag    | correlated_weight
> ---------: | :----- | ----------------:
>          1 | fun    |       25.00000000
>          1 | winter |       25.00000000
>          2 | fun    |        3.33333000
>          2 | love   |        3.33333000
>          2 | summer |       26.66664000
>          3 | fun    |       13.33332000
>          3 | love   |       16.66665000
>          3 | summer |        3.33333000
>          4 | fun    |       37.50000000
>          4 | love   |       12.50000000
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `article_id`,  SUM(`weight`)/COUNT(*) proc_per_id FROM article_tags GROUP BY `article_id`
> ```
>
> ```
> article_id | proc_per_id
> ---------: | ----------:
>          1 |     50.0000
>          2 |     33.3333
>          3 |     33.3333
>          4 |     50.0000
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `tag`,  SUM(`weight`)/COUNT(*) proc_per_tag, COUNT(*) count_tag FROM article_tags GROUP BY `tag`
> ```
>
> ```
> tag    | proc_per_tag | count_tag
> :----- | -----------: | --------:
> fun    |      43.7500 |         4
> winter |      50.0000 |         1
> love   |      28.3333 |         3
> summer |      45.0000 |         2
> ```

> ```
> #All Articles that have Tag fun and a corrlated weight betweeen 20 aand 40
> SELECT 
>     `article_id`
> FROM
>     (SELECT 
>         at1.`article_id`,
>             `tag`,
>             (`weight` / 100 * proc_per_id) correlated_weight
>     FROM
>         article_tags at1
>     INNER JOIN (SELECT 
>         `article_id`, SUM(`weight`) / COUNT(*) proc_per_id
>     FROM
>         article_tags
>     GROUP BY `article_id`) at2 ON at1.`article_id` = at2.`article_id`) t1
> WHERE
>     `tag` = 'fun'
>         AND correlated_weight BETWEEN 20 AND 40
> ```
>
> ```
> | article_id |
> | ---------: |
> |          1 |
> |          4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22388a738b30bd8008516625a42d5d22)*

Select one of them

> ```
> SELECT 
>     at1.`article_id`, at1.`tag`, (at1.`weight` / 100 * at2. `weight` ) correlated_weight
> FROM
>     article_tags at1
>         INNER JOIN
>     (SELECT 
>         tag ,`weight` 
>     FROM
>         article_tags
>     WHERE `article_id` = 4) at2 ON at1.`tag` = at2.`tag`AND at1.`tag` = 'fun' AND at1.`article_id` = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> article_id | tag | correlated_weight
> ---------: | :-- | ----------------:
>          1 | fun |           37.5000
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     at1.`article_id`, at1.`tag`, (at1.`weight` / 100 * at2. `weight` ) correlated_weight
> FROM
>     article_tags at1
>         INNER JOIN
>     (SELECT 
>         tag ,`weight` 
>     FROM
>         article_tags
>     WHERE `article_id` = 4) at2 ON at1.`tag` = at2.`tag`
> WHERE at1.`tag` = 'fun' AND at1.`article_id` = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> article_id | tag | correlated_weight
> ---------: | :-- | ----------------:
>          1 | fun |           37.5000
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     at1.`article_id`
>     , at1.`tag`
>     , (at1.`weight` / 100 * (SELECT `weight` FROM  article_tags
>                              WHERE `article_id` = 4 AND tag = at1.tag) ) correlated_weight
> FROM
>     article_tags at1
> WHERE at1.`tag` = 'fun' AND at1.`article_id` = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> article_id | tag | correlated_weight
> ---------: | :-- | ----------------:
>          1 | fun |           37.5000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=074f83e1f0cc9d50d2667ca31c6f00f3)*

Comment: This changes the weight based on number of tags per article id. So article 1's tag weights gets divided by 2 as there are 2 tags for article 1. I need to correlate article 1's tag weights to article 4. So article 4's `fun` weight is 75%, therefore when comparing to article 1, article 1's weight becomes 50% * 75% = 37.5%

Comment: as stated before, then you have to exolain how to calculate, because iffollowed your article_ud 4 by the letter and i till today don't understand

Comment: i have added all tag related numbers i can thnk of, see if one of these can be used to calculate your wanted result

Comment: I'm not sure how else to describe my issue. I wanna find other relevant articles based on the article I'm currently viewing. So the calculation of the correlated weights must be a comparison between article 1,2 and 3 compared to article 4's tags.

Comment: You don't describe absoöutly nothing please expalin how the values if the first select where for example the result is `4 | fun    |       37.50000000 ` should be modified, i posted all possible queries that could have an effect on it, but i can't because you didn't explain how they correlate

Comment: I'm trying to compare 2 fields: tag + weight. So when comparing the tags of article 1 and article 4 I need to compare the weight both articles have of the identical tags. They both have fun. 1 weight fun 50% and 4 weight it 75%. 75% of 50% is 37.5%

Comment: that makes my last SELECT it uses fun to show all that have a certain similar weight.

Comment: But I'm not looking for similar weight. I wanna score article 1's weight based on how article 4 weighs the same tag.

Comment: Thanks @nbk - this certainly gives me an idea of how to achieve my goal :)